# How to filter array with multiple conditions in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    search: '',
    itemsList: [],
    isLoaded: false,
    selectNum: status,
    userList: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Prem",
        status: "ok"
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "Chandu",
        status: "notok"
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        name: "Shravya",
        status: "ok"
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        name: "kirt",
        status: "notok"
      }
    ]
  },
  created() {
    vm.itemsList = [];
    vm.isLoaded = true;
  },
  computed: {
    filteredAndSorted() {
      // function to compare names  
      function compare(a, b) {
        if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
        if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
        return 0;
      }

      return this.userList.filter(user => {
        return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase()) &&
          user.status === this.selectNum
      }).sort(compare)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="isLoaded">
    <select v-model="selectNum" name="text">
      <option :value="status">ok</option>
      <option :value="status">notok</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="search-wrapper">
    <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search title.." />
    <label>Search Users:</label>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user in filteredAndSorted">{{user.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to achieve functionality like,

Initially the array will be loaded with the help of v-for.
At the top I have two options called search-bar and dropdown. Where With the help of those I am trying to filler the array.

**Where with search-bar, I want to filter array values.
With dropdown, I want to filter the status present in each array.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like following snippet:

```js
const app = new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
      itemsList: [],
      isLoaded: false,
      selectNum: '',
      userList: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "Prem",
          status:"ok"
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "Chandu",
          status:"notok"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "Shravya",
          status:"ok"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "kirt",
          status:"notok"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.isLoaded = true;
  },
  computed: {
    filteredAndSorted(){
     function compare(a, b) {
       if (a.name < b.name) return -1;
       if (a.name > b.name) return 1;
       return 0;
     }
     const res = this.userList.filter(user => {
          return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.search.toLowerCase())
       }).sort(compare)
     if (this.selectNum) {
       return res.filter(user => user.status === this.selectNum )
     }
     return res
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-if="isLoaded">
    <select v-model="selectNum" name="text"> 
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select status</option>
      <option value="ok">ok</option>
      <option value="notok">notok</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="search-wrapper">  
    <input type="text" v-model="search" placeholder="Search title.."/>
        <label>Search Users:</label>
  </div>  
  <ul>
    <li v-for="user in filteredAndSorted">{{user.name}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is error at line 25

```js
// ...
  created(){
    var vm = this;
    vm.itemsList = [];  // => j is undefined
    vm.isLoaded = true;
  },
// ...
```

Comment: Yes search-bar is working fine. But from dropdown I am able to select only id options. But the functionality is not working. Where for dropdown based on id, i need to show the users

Comment: if you want to limit the result using dropdown 
https://codepen.io/huudai09/pen/wvrPwoN?editors=1011